# handling of many DOM changes

Tags: javascript, dom, coffeescript

I have a project where I load parts of my content over an ajax request. I get everytime the same structures of information (json) and I tried to make a coffeescript class for each DOM-Layout which presents these structures.

Im working on the first DOM-representation for these structures and my code is blowing up by statements like `controls.append @Legende.content.messageSpan` or `@Legende.content.itself.append $(labelNew).html "Name: "`

The problem: There are 3 following DOM-representations i have to implement and that will blow up my code.

My question is as follows: What is the main practice to handle many DOM-tree changes and/or prevent enlarging the number of files and increased file sizes?

Comment: If you are not using any template engine, you have to manipulate your DOM step by step.

Comment: I thought I use the classes as templates with a parent DOM element as param in my constructor which references to a node where to append all my elements. But these are huge classes and methods

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really have a huge amount of DOM changes based on changes in an underlying model, its best to use a library that allows you to bind your dom to the model implicitly without requiring explicit changes.  2 of the most popular libraries for this are

- [knockoutjs](http://knockoutjs.com/) (*does this and nothing else*)
- [angularjs](http://angularjs.org/) (*does this and a whole lot of other things you may or may not need*)

KnockoutJS is simpler and more approachable in general.

Angular is a bit more complex and opinionated, but scales well as projects get big.

These libraries work by adding annotations to html like this (Knockout-based example)

```
<tr>
    <td><input data-bind="value: name" /></td>
    <td><select data-bind="options: $root.availableMeals, value: meal"></select></td>
    <td data-bind="text: formattedPrice"></td>
    <td><a href="#" data-bind="click: $root.removeSeat">Remove</a></td>
</tr>
```

You can set up the dom however you like and it will automatically change to reflect the data you have bound to it.

Comment: Also, useful variant - Backbone + Marionnette + ModelBinder for binding DOM and models

Comment: @IvanAntropov sure. You could keep listing these all day.

Comment: Do you have an example of what angularjs brings more?

Comment: @felix just look at the link.  They list it all out on their introduction page.   In short: routing, ease of testing, helper functions for Ajax, reuseable GUI components, structure that encourages DRY coding and no global scope variables